# Qt QScrollArea Scroll Speed

Tags: performance, qt, scroll, qscrollarea

Is there a way to reduce the scroll speed on a QScrollArea? When I scroll by the mouse wheel, it jumps passed the content. So yeah is there a way to adjust it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set `singleStep` (in pixels) of area's scroll bars:

```
ui->scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setSingleStep(2);
```